# Angular 6 - Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date for pipe "DatePipe"

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular6

*Hello Friends,*

I am phasing an issue related to ***Date*** conversion into a *desire* format.

Actually, *REST API* sends date into `Milliseconds format`. which I would like to convert it into a specific date-format & would like to inject it into my date-picket model/ui-component. Here, `yyyy-MM-dd` format is my **desire** format.

`Error` is something like, `Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date for pipe "DatePipe".`

FYI - 
[image]

My Code is something likewise,

```
this.rest.getprofiledata()
           .((resp) =>{
           this.data = resp;
           this.personal = this.data["message"];
           this.d = new Date(this.personal.dob);
           this.personal.dob = this.d;
               var day = this.d.getDate();
               var mon = this.d.getMonth();
               var year = this.d.getFullYear();
               var dy = this.d.getDay();
               dt = new Date(dy,mon,year);
               this.personal.dob = dt
           } );
```

Comment: we need some more info. please update with the html where you are using the DatePipe and a sample of the object you are using.

Comment: It looks like your call to the Date function to create the new date is wrong, with three variables it takes year, month, day; in that order. Also, you are using the day of the week (dy variable) instead of day of the month (day variable) in the date, I can imagine you would want to use the other.

Answer (score 0):

On several occasions I used the date as

```
Today is {{myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd':'UTC'}}
```

This works for me